# Convert SCSS file to CSS take too much time in debian

Tags: linux, css, sass

I'm using SCSS 3.4.17 on debian, when i'm compiling some SCSS files with imported other SCSS files into it, its take too much. if i'm converting small files then it's work well.

Comment: Is there a question? Do you have some examples? What debian are you using? "Too much time" compared to what?

Comment: Yes, this is question, and my Debian version is "Linux goobing-debian7-x86 3.2.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.2.54-2 i686 GNU/Linux
". i'm compiling the SCSS file to CSS using this Debian and that compiling process take too much time (approx 5 min).